# Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Thread-5,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android

What does the following exception mean; how can I fix it?
**This is the code:**

```
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String message = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext)
                                .setTitle("title：")
                                .setMessage(TmpPwd)
                                .setPositiveButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }
```

**This is the exception:**

```
    W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Thread-5,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:205)
```

Comment: Yeah, you might be calling this code on a non-UI thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your `onResponse` show your dialog like below inside a UI thread

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
  new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext)
       .setTitle("title：")
       .setMessage(TmpPwd)
       .setPositiveButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    })
    .show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
 h.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
  //here show dialog
}
});
```